# Start a background task from windows 7 cmd?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

I'd like to start a command from the `cmd` command line in Windows 7 and have it run completely in the background.

Basically I'm looking for the functionality that the *nix `&` provides.

So far I've found `start` which starts the command in a new `cmd` window, and I've found `start /B` which doesn't open a new window, drops back to the command line, but keeps the process attached to the `cmd.exe` process from which it was started (so if you close `cmd.exe` it kills the process).

Is this possible?  It's so simple in *nix I'm having trouble believing it can't be done, but who knows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only easy way I know from `cmd` is using [`psexec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533) from Sysinternals process tools.

```
psexec -d your_command
```

could do the trick. (That tool has a bunch of useful options, and it can start processes on remote machines too. Quite useful.)

I remember having had to resort to `at` and/or `schtasks` in a tight spot, but... don't do that ;)

If you don't want a new window at all, but can stand one that disappears immediately (you'll see it pop up then leave), you can use a VBScript wrapper. (There are a few variations on this all over the tubes.)

#### launcher.vbs

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run "your_cmd_file_with_full_path.cmd", 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Then:

```
psexec -d cscript launcher.vbs
```

Comment: D'oh, still opens a window.  To be fair this may be the fault of vboxheadless and not your methodology.

Comment: Well, don't know how to do it with absolutely no disturbance. Added another layer in there that hides itself pretty fast. That's about all I know, hopefully someone who actually knows Windows will come up with a real solution :)

Comment: Interesting, I'll try it in a minute.  It seems rdp to my headless vm from the host (which itself was over rdp) has borked something along along the way.

Comment: It seems the executing this script directly with cscript had the desired effect.  I find it hard to believe there's not a simpler way considering it's a single character in *nix

Answer (score 0):

open a powershell window (just type in powershell in command area in windows start menu), start-job -command "whatever your command is"

Comment: Cannot bind paramter 'ScriptBlock'. Cannot convert value... etc.